# How does VPN software 'hijack' packets for tunneling?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, ipsec, tcpip

## My current mental model

1. An application interacts with the operating system to produce an OSI model stack-based packet process - subsequent layers of encapsulation
2. Somewhere along the line before the packet is encapsulated in an ethernet frame, but assuming after it has been given an IP header, the VPN software hijacks it and adds another encapsulation layer to it (AH header and encrypts payload) for VPN tunnel routing
3. new packet with (probably) ESP and AH headers and an encrypted payload is passed to the network interface driver which gives it an ethernet frame and transmits on the wire

What I don't understand is actually how the VPN software hijacks the interprocess communication pipes like this - how it knows which applications to hijack, and how it can do this selectively without modifying all network communication from the host.

## Please explain how a VPN process will intercept IPC destined for the network interface driver

Comment: If someone could go so far as to explain which kernel operations govern this type of process I would also appreciate it - I hadn't found this information anywhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VPN software usually works by adding a 'virtual' network interface to your system.

It uses plain old routing to direct traffic via the tunnel interface, (beware, very generalized) save for the endpoint host which it will communicate with the regular way.

Comment: Oh, so it sets the default interface to the virtual interface and redirects traffic from the virtual interface to the real interface, and then uses the virtual interface to apply IPSec? Okay that works, thank you =)

Comment: A bit oversimplified. Routing tables play a rather key component in whether packets are routed over the VPN or not.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily set the default interface to the virtual interface.  The main thing is the Routing table.  In some implementations, yes, the 0.0.0.0 route will be set to the virtual interface, this is in use to keep most of the traffic going through the tunnel.  Otherwise it will just add routes to the internal network with the virtual interface set for those routes.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't "hijack" anything.

When your application needs to reach a system that is behind the other end of a VPN, it will send the packets in the tunnel.

If you are using a client to connect to a VPN then your PC is doing the encrypting part (and decrypting when receiving packets). It will encrypt and encapsulate the packets at the creation and send it to the other peer in the tunnel.

That peer will then decrypt the packets.

If you are going in a B2B tunnel, then the peer on your side of the tunnel is encrypting/decrypting the packets.

Comment: Right, but when "application X" creates a packet and passes it to the network interface card driver, the driver transmits it - if VPN software is going to encapsulate and encrypt this packet, it needs to be able to modify the communications channel to support the VPN configuration - EG: firefox doesn't just start encrypting packets for a VPN without some additional plug-in, whereas there are system-wide VPN software clients that provide services to all the applications that would use network services on a given machine.

Comment: @Andrew I'd suggest doing a little research on how routing works. Essentially, you're asking how VPNs route packets which cannot be properly explained without knowledge of routing.

Comment: @Andrew - applications don't pass packets to network drivers. Applications tell the OS, "Hey I have this data, please ensure it gets sent out properly.", then the OS takes the data, looks at its own routing table, and does what it needs to do to send the packet. The application typically has **zero** knowledge of what happens to the data after it hands it off to the OS. If the default route points through the VPN tunnel, then everything gets encrypted. If only a subnet or two point through the tunnel, then only that traffic will go through the VPN.